# How can I call a vb.net function from angularJS code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, angularjs

I'm trying to pass data stored in a dynamically created table to the server, and while I can access the data in my angularJS controller, I am having difficulty learning how to pass this data to the server to process.

Here is my angularjs function that is able to access my table data, its just passing the data and calling my vb.net function that I am having trouble with.

```
$scope.requestThatCertificatesBeEmailed = function () {
    for (index = 0; index < $scope.requests.length; ++index) {
        alert('For loop entered')
        var submittedEmailAddressString = $scope.requests[index].emailAddress;
        var submittedCertificateTypeString = $scope.requests[index].certificateType;
        var submittedSearchTypeString = $scope.requests[index].searchType;
        var submittedSearchString = $scope.requests[index].submittedNumbers;

        alert(submittedSearchTypeString);

        $http.post("/Home/NewTextFile", { submittedEmailAddress: submittedEmailAddressString, submittedCertificateType: submittedCertificateTypeString, submittedSearchType: submittedSearchTypeString, submittedSearch: submittedSearchString }).error(function () {
            $scope.requests = [];
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to post/put the data back to the server.  If you are working in a ASP.NET WebForms application, you will likely need to pass the value as JSON to the server in a hidden input field.  If you are working in an ASP.NET MVC application, you should be able to invoke a controller action sending in the JSON table data from javascript.

Your action method in your MVC Controller should look like this:

```
<HttpPost> _
Public Function NewTextFile(submittedEmailAddress As String, submittedCertificateType As String, submittedSearchType As String, submittedSearch As String) As ActionResult
    'do some work
End Function
```

Using jQuery, you could invoke the controller action like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/NewTextFile',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        submittedEmailAddress: submittedEmailAddressString, 
        submittedCertificateType: submittedCertificateTypeString, 
        submittedSearchType: submittedSearchTypeString, 
        submittedSearch: submittedSearchString 
    }),
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Below is an AngularJS example I whipped together:

On/referenced from the View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('httpExample', [])
            .controller('ContactController', ['$scope', '$http',
                function ($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
                    $scope.contact = { userName: '', firstName: '', lastName: '' };

                    $scope.get = function () {
                        $scope.code = null;
                        $scope.response = null;

                        $http.get('/Home/Contact').
                        success(function (data, status) {
                            $scope.status = status;
                            $scope.data = data;
                            $scope.contact = data;
                        }).
                        error(function (data, status) {
                            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                            $scope.contact = { userName: '', firstName: '', lastName: '' }
                            $scope.status = status;
                        });
                    };

                    $scope.post = function () {
                        $scope.code = null;
                        $scope.response = null;

                        $http.post('/Home/Contact', $scope.contact).
                        success(function (data, status) {
                            $scope.status = status;
                            $scope.data = data;
                        }).
                        error(function (data, status) {
                            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                            $scope.status = status;
                        });

                    };

                }]);
</script>
```

Somewhere in the body:

```
<div>
    <div ng-app="httpExample">
        <div ng-controller="ContactController">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Contact</legend>
                Username: <input type="text" ng-model="contact.userName"/><br/>
                Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="contact.lastName"/><br/>
                First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="contact.firstName"/><br/>
            </fieldset>
            <br />
            <button id="getbtn" ng-click="get()">get</button>
            <button id="postbtn" ng-click="post()">post</button><br/><br/>

            <pre>http status code: {{status}}</pre>
            <pre>http response data: {{data}}</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your MVC server side Home controller has methods that look like this:

```
<HttpGet> _
Public Function Contact() As JsonResult
    Dim contact = New With { .userName = "smithjk", .firstName = "John", .lastName = "Smith" }
    Return Json(contact, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function

<HttpPost> _
Public Function Contact(userName As String, firstName As String, lastName As String) As ActionResult
    'do some work
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(userName)
    Return New EmptyResult()
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I am indeed using ASP.NET MVC application. I'll start doing research on the keywords you included. 

I edited in my angularJS function in my question's post. You can see my feeble attempt to call the vb.net function but it unfortunately does not get called. Please do comment back with additional details. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for this. It definitely gets me headed in the right direction. For this project I am using AngularJS instead of Jquery. If it is not too difficult, could you translate your code to AngularJS? Either way, thank you so much.

Comment: @BryanTorres I think the angular example above should help you out